# Export-Csv -Append isn't actually appending second set of items

Tags: powershell, append, export-csv

I am trying to take two CSV files of users and append one to the other. I start by importing the CSVs and selecting only the columns I want from each, then moving those edited CSVs to temp CSV files (*Temp1.csv* and *Temp2.csv*). I then take the two temp CSV files and remove the first line (the header) using `Select-Object -Skip 1` and set those to two new temp CSVs (*Temp3.csv* and *Temp4.csv*). Next, I import *Temp3.csv* as a variable, then immediately export that CSV as my final file. Finally, I import *Temp4.csv* as a variable, then export it to the same file name that I saved Temp3, but with the `-Append` and `-Force` flags. However, Temp4 is not appended to Temp3 as I would expect. I feel I'm missing something obvious, and this almost definitely not the best method for writing this script. Everything works up till that last part, though. Any help would be appreciated.

I followed Example 6 of the Export-CSV PowerShell doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6

I've also tried combinations of `Set-Content` and `Get-Content` with combinations of `Import-CSV` and `Export-CSV`. Below are my most recent version and associated outputs:

```
# Get today's date to add to the end of the user upload file
$importDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy.MM.dd"

# Import the record, but only select the employee's email address, preferred first name, and last name
# and place those three columns' worth of data in the temp csv file 
Import-Csv -Path "EmployeeList.csv" |
Select-Object "Email","FName","LName" |
Where-Object {$_."Email" -ne ""} |
Export-Csv -Path "Temp1.csv" -NoTypeInformation

# Import the record, but only select the employee's email address, preferred first name, and last name
# and place those three columns' worth of data in the temp csv file
Import-Csv -Path "ContractorList.csv" |
Select-Object "Email","FName","LName" |
Where-Object {$_.Email -like "*@company.com"} |
Export-Csv -Path "Temp2.csv" -NoTypeInformation

# Remove column headings
$tempCSVone = (Get-Content -Path "Temp1.csv")
$tempCSVone | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content -Path "Temp3.csv"

# Remove column heading
$tempCSVtwo = (Get-Content -Path "Temp2.csv")
$tempCSVtwo | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content -Path "Temp4.csv"

# Export to final csv
$tempCSVthree = (Import-Csv -Path "Temp3.csv")
$tempCSVthree | Export-Csv -Path "TempFinal_$importDate.csv"-NoTypeInformation

# Append to TempFInal
$tempCSVfour = (Import-Csv -Path "Temp4.csv")
$tempCSVfour | Export-CSv -Path "TempFinal_$importDate.csv" -Append -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

```
Results in CSV files: 

Temp1.csv
Email   FName   LName
a@company.com   A   AAA
b@company.com   B   BBB
c@company.com   C   CCC

Temp2.csv
Email   FName   LName
d@company.com   D   DDD
e@company.com   E   EEE
f@company.com   F   FFF

Temp3.csv
a@company.com   A   AAA
b@company.com   B   BBB
c@company.com   C   CCC

Temp4.csv
d@company.com   D   DDD
e@company.com   E   EEE
f@company.com   F   FFF

Expected result in TempFinal.csv:
a@company.com   A   AAA
b@company.com   B   BBB
c@company.com   C   CCC
d@company.com   D   DDD
e@company.com   E   EEE
f@company.com   F   FFF

Actual result in TempFinal.csv:
a@company.com   A   AAA
b@company.com   B   BBB
c@company.com   C   CCC
```

Comment: You need to define a `-Header` for the `Import-Csv -Path "Temp3.csv"` and `...Temp4.csv` otherwise the first row will taken as a header which are different for both files. Why not removing the header in the final stage, after the append?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things, after having files

- imported, same properties and order
- simply -Append the 2nd to the same file:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\09\12\SO_57910524.ps1
Import-Csv -Path "EmployeeList.csv" |
  Select-Object Email,FName,LName |
    Where-Object Email -ne "" | 
      Export-Csv -Path "Temp1.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Import-Csv -Path "ContractorList.csv" |
  Select-Object Email,FName,LName |
    Where-Object Email -like "*@company.com" |
      Export-Csv -Path "Temp1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

---

```
> Get-Content .\Temp1.csv
"Email","FName","LName"
"a@company.com","A","AAA"
"b@company.com","B","BBB"
"c@company.com","C","CCC"
"d@company.com","D","DDD"
"e@company.com","E","EEE"
"f@company.com","F","FFF"
```

Comment: So, if the headers in the files don't match, does this still work this way? I guess I can rename the headers to match in both files, first, then do this part.

Comment: They ***DO*** match due to the `Select-Object`. If the *real* headers don't you could use `calculated property` to rename them. I.e. `Select-Object @{n='Email';e={$_.RealpropertyEmail}}`

Comment: Sorry, That's what I was implying with my comment. Okay, I'll try it this way. Thanks!